# Unable to validate ProxyTicketValidator

Tags: jakarta-ee, cas

I am currently setting up dev environment for my project but they have used CAS for central authentication & I am very new to CAS. Still I could see cas login page for dev environment which uses ldap server for user authentication but when I click on login button it throws exception. I attach link to configuring Jboss for ssl connection which I use but still I am getting same exception. Please help

[Jboss https configuration](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/HOWTO+Configure+JBoss+for+HTTPS)

```
2012-12-17 15:33:51,575 INFO  [STDOUT] 15:33:51,575 ERROR [CASReceipt] edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.CASAuthenticationException: Unable to validate ProxyTicketValidator [[edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.ProxyTicketValidator proxyList=[null] [edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.ServiceTicketValidator casValidateUrl=[https://IN-HODPDT-0010.glenmark.com/cas/serviceValidate] ticket=[ST-1-KRWufbKdoPaes3pBNKeBJEE30gXjF2lIcTy-20] service=[http%3A%2F%2FIN-HODPDT-0010.glenmark.com%2Ftraveldesk%2Flogin%2Floginaction.do] renew=false]]]
2012-12-17 15:33:51,575 INFO  [STDOUT] 15:33:51,575 ERROR [CASFilter] edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.CASAuthenticationException: Unable to validate ProxyTicketValidator [[edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.ProxyTicketValidator proxyList=[null] [edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.ServiceTicketValidator casValidateUrl=[https://IN-HODPDT-0010.glenmark.com/cas/serviceValidate] ticket=[ST-1-KRWufbKdoPaes3pBNKeBJEE30gXjF2lIcTy-20] service=[http%3A%2F%2FIN-HODPDT-0010.glenmark.com%2Ftraveldesk%2Flogin%2Floginaction.do] renew=false]]]
2012-12-17 15:33:51,575 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/traveldesk].[action]] Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem the SSL of your CAS server. This guide might help you : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/SSL+Troubleshooting+and+Reference+Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You should import your server.cer to your client JRE !

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/JRE/LIB/SECURITY/CACERTS" -storepass changeit -file c:\myserver.cer
```